# "Gradle - Dependencias" Google AdMob - error

Tags: android-studio, gradle, admob

estoy tratando de implementar publicidad en una de mis app's.
El problema viene cuando tengo que agregar lo siguiente en el Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'
```

Le doy en Sync Now y al momento que acaba de sincronizar, me tira error en lo siguiente:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

¿Saben como arreglarlo? Ya cambié la vesion a la 26.0.0 y aun así aparece el error.

Esto es lo que tengo dentro de "dependencias"

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
```

}

Comment: ¿Puedes postear lo que tienes en `dependencies` del archivo `build.gradle`? Saludos

Comment: Listo @MauricioContreras el problema me sale cuando agrego lo de AdMob

Comment: Prueba agregando `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'` justo después de tu linea conflictiva y comenta los resultados.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Ni así amigo, me sigue marcando error.

Comment: Hay alguna dependencia por allí conflictiva. ¿Has visto el árbol de dependencias? Si puedes postear la estructura del mismo podríamos ver si existe alguna cosa que esté rota o que pida algo diferente. Si usas Linux intenta con `./gradlew app:dependencies` o con `./gradlew app:androidDependencies`

Comment: Solucioné el error agregando estas tres lineas de codigo: " implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0' "

Comment: Me alegra. Puedes publicar la respuesta para que le sea de utilidad a quien tenga un problema igual o parecido al tuyo. Es totalmente válido. Saludos